# PHP query also show results for ID 75

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have the following query. For some reason it's not showing results for the user under id: 75, which is me of course.

```
SELECT IF(friends.sender = 75, friends.recipient, friends.sender) AS id, users.firstname, users.lastname, feed.date, feed.time, feed.text, feed.userID, feed.ip
FROM friends
JOIN users
    ON (users.id = IF(friends.sender = 75, friends.recipient, friends.sender))
JOIN feed 
    ON (users.id = feed.userID)
WHERE friends.sender = 75
    OR friends.recipient = 75
 AND friends.status = 1
ORDER BY feed.date DESC, feed.time DESC
```

Comment: What would you like us to do? A bit too vague. Can you provide an example of what you're expecting to show up or what errors you get?

Comment: Right, sorry. I always forget to include that xD Basicly its displaying the messages being posted on feed, and showing only user 75's friend's posts. How ever its not allowing me to see my own, where I'm user 75.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a little bit of a guess at what you're attempting to accomplish, but assuming you want to return a list of users and their friends, something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, 
    feed.date, feed.time, feed.text, feed.userID, feed.ip
FROM users 
JOIN friends
    ON users.id IN (friends.sender, friends.recipient)
JOIN feed 
    ON (users.id = feed.userID)
WHERE 75 IN (friends.sender,friends.recipient) 
    AND friends.status = 1
ORDER BY feed.date DESC, feed.time DESC
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45175/5)